# Escrever uma função NaipeDeTruco(naipe) que retorne um array de strings com os números + os naipes das cartas

Tags: javascript

Estou resolvendo o exercício abaixo, mas estou tendo alguns problemas:

> Escrever uma função naipeDeTruco, que dado um naipe, devolva uma lista de strings, uma por cada carta desse naipe seguindo as cartas do truco. Ex:

```
naipeDeTruco("espadas")

["1 de espadas", "2 de espadas", "3 de espadas" ..., "12 de espadas"]
```

Lembre-se que as cartas de truco incluem todas as cartas numeradas de 1 a 12, com exceção das cartas 8 e 9.

**Obs:**

1. Lembre-se que veremos como resultado um conjunto de strings, nesse caso, respeite bastante a concatenação dos espaços, e as letras maiúsculas e minúsculas.
2. Como um contador neste caso você terá que criar um array dentro da função. Da mesma forma, você tem que colocar cada uma das strings correspondente e no final da função você tem que devolver o contador.
3. Lembre-se de não colocar um dado específico como parâmetro, para que nossa função tem que servir a todos os naipes do baralho.

**Aqui está o meu código:**

```
function naipeDeTruco(naipe){

    var arrayDeNaipes= [];

    for (var i=1; i <=12; i++){

      if((naipe == "espadas") && ([i]!=8) && ([i]!=9) && ([i]!=10)){
        arrayDeNaipes.push([i]+ " de espadas");
        }   
            else if((naipe == "paus") && ([i]!=8) && ([i]!=9) && ([i]!=10)){
            arrayDeNaipes.push([i]+ " de paus");
            } 
                else if((naipe == "copas") && ([i]!=8) && ([i]!=9) && ([i]!=10)){
                arrayDeNaipes.push([i]+ " de copas");
                } 
                    else if((naipe == "ouro") && ([i]!=8) && ([i]!=9) && ([i]!=10)){
                    arrayDeNaipes.push([i]+ " de ouro");
                    } 
         }
    return arrayDeNaipes;
}
```

Teste meu código neste site (https://jsfiddle.net/) e ele está funcionando, está retornando o que é esperado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Contudo, quando eu vou validá-lo na plataforma da digital house, o seguinte erro aparece:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

OBS: No enunciado é pedido que os número 8 e 9 não sejam retornados. No meu código, eu coloquei pra não retornar o 8 e 9 e deu o erro acima. Depois modifiquei para não retornar o 8, 9 e o 10, mas dá o mesmo erro.

Alguém sabe o que pode estar acontecendo?

Comment: realmente seu código não retorna, deveria falar com o suporte do seu curso para verificar o código do lado deles

Comment: Dá para simplificar esse monte de `if`: https://jsfiddle.net/x54Lozfh/

Comment: Oi @hkotsubo, obrigado pela ajuda. Eu fiz desta forma abaixo e passou no teste.

`function naipeDeTruco(naipe){
     var naipeEscolhido = naipe;

       var cartas = [
       "1 de "+naipeEscolhido, "2 de "+naipeEscolhido, "3 de "+naipeEscolhido, 
       "4 de "+naipeEscolhido, "5 de "+naipeEscolhido, "6 de "+naipeEscolhido, 
       "7 de "+naipeEscolhido, "10 de "+naipeEscolhido, "11 de "+naipeEscolhido, "12 de "+naipeEscolhido];

        return cartas;
    }

console.log(naipeDeTruco("espadas"));`

Answer (score 1):

agradeço o tempo de vocês em me ajudar. Encontrei essa solução aqui. Retirei os IFs, passei os parâmetros e concatenei as strings junto.

```html
    function naipeDeTruco(naipe){
     var naipeEscolhido = naipe;

       var cartas = [
       "1 de "+naipeEscolhido, "2 de "+naipeEscolhido, "3 de "+naipeEscolhido, 
       "4 de "+naipeEscolhido, "5 de "+naipeEscolhido, "6 de "+naipeEscolhido, 
       "7 de "+naipeEscolhido, "10 de "+naipeEscolhido, "11 de "+naipeEscolhido, "12 de "+naipeEscolhido];

        return cartas;
    }

console.log(naipeDeTruco("espadas"));
```

Answer (score -1):

```
function naipeDeTruco(naipe){

var arrayDeNaipes= [];

for (var i=1; i <=12; i++){

  **if((naipe == "espadas") && ([i]!=8) && ([i]!=9))**{//Retira o !=10 dessa parte do código
    arrayDeNaipes.push([i]+ " de espadas");
    }   
        else if((naipe == "paus") && ([i]!=8) && ([i]!=9 && [i]!=10)){
        arrayDeNaipes.push([i]+ " de paus");
        } 
            else if((naipe == "copas") && ([i]!=8) && ([i]!=9 && [i]!=10)){
            arrayDeNaipes.push([i]+ " de copas");
            } 
                else if((naipe == "ouro") && ([i]!=8) && ([i]!=9 && [i]!=10)){
                arrayDeNaipes.push([i]+ " de ouro");
                } 
     }
return arrayDeNaipes;
}
console.log(naipeDeTruco("espadas"))
```